# Impossible to charge my dropDown list

Tags: java, swing

My dropdown list indicates several incorrect elements in my form...[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49ilS.png)
I have an error message.
**"at presentation.JDAlbuInsert.fillComponents(JDAlbuInsert.java:146)"**
Here is the line:

```
private void fillComponents()
    {

        ArrayList <Chanteur> cha = daoCha.selectChanteurs();
        for (int i=0;i<cha.size();i++)
            jComboCha.addItem(cha.get(i));

    }
```

So, my problem is in my file JifChanteur I hava this...
Perhaps that the problem is the DaoCha ???? Do you have an idea ?

```
public class JIFChanteurs extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    /** Creates new form FenetreAppareils2 */
    public JIFChanteurs() {
        ((BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
        initComponents();
        fillComponents();
    }

    private void fillComponents()
    {
        /* charger toutes les cat�gories */
        /*
        ArrayList<Categorie> listeCats = daoCat.selectCategories();
        listeCats.add(0, new Categorie(0,"*")); // ajoute une cat bidon : 0 signifie toutes les cat
        for (Categorie cat : listeCats) {
            jComboBoxCat.addItem(cat); // on ins�re des objets dans les combo, mais ils sont affich�s gr�ce � leurs m�thodes toString() !
        }*/
    }
    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTableCha = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setBorder(null);
        setTitle("Instruments");
        setVisible(true);

        jTableCha.setModel(myChaModel);
        jTableCha.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        /* initialisation des largeurs de colonnes */
        javax.swing.table.TableColumn column = null;
        column = jTableCha.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        column.setPreferredWidth(50);
        column = jTableCha.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        column.setPreferredWidth(150);
        column = jTableCha.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        column.setPreferredWidth(150);
        column = jTableCha.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        column.setPreferredWidth(150);
        column = jTableCha.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
        column.setPreferredWidth(150);
        column.setPreferredWidth(50);

        /* jTableCha.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(myModel)); */
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTableCha);

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jScrollPane1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 506, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jScrollPane1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 379, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(28, 28, 28))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        



private void refreshModel()
{

}


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTableCha;
    // End of variables declaration                   



    private DAOChanteurs daoCha = Factory.getDAOChanteurs();;
    private TableModelChanteurs myChaModel = new TableModelChanteurs(daoCha.selectChanteurs());;


}
```

And my class JDAAlbIns

```
public class JDAlbuInsert extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /** Creates new form JDApparInsert */
    public JDAlbuInsert(java.awt.Frame parent, String titre) {
        super(parent, titre, true);
        initComponents();
        fillComponents();
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(jButtonOK);
        setLocation(parent.getX()+parent.getWidth()/3, parent.getY()+parent.getHeight()/3);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextIdent = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextTitre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboCha = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jDateChooserDate = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButtonOK = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButtonAnnul = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Ident");

        jLabel2.setText("Description");

        jLabel3.setText("Date");

        jLabel4.setText("Nom");

        jDateChooserDate.setDateFormatString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                    .add(jLabel2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(jLabel1)
                    .add(jLabel3)
                    .add(jLabel4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .add(11, 11, 11)
                .add(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                    .add(jComboCha, 0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(jTextIdent, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(jTextTitre, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(jDateChooserDate, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(126, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                    .add(jLabel1)
                    .add(jTextIdent, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                    .add(jLabel2)
                    .add(jTextTitre, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(jLabel3)
                    .add(jDateChooserDate, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                    .add(jLabel4)
                    .add(jComboCha, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .add(185, 185, 185))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jButtonOK.setText("OK");
        jButtonOK.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonOKActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel2.add(jButtonOK);

        jButtonAnnul.setText("Annuler");
        jButtonAnnul.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonAnnulActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel2.add(jButtonAnnul);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButtonAnnulActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
// TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                            

    private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
// TODO add your handling code here:
        Album alb = new Album();
        alb.setCodeA(jTextIdent.getText().toUpperCase()); //setIdentApp
        alb.setTitreA(jTextTitre.getText());
        alb.setSortieA(jDateChooserDate.getDate());
        alb.setCatApp((Chanteur)jComboCha.getSelectedItem());

        boolean ok = daoAlb.insertAlbum(alb);
        if (!ok)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insertion impossible !","Avertissement",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        this.dispose();
    }                                         

    private void fillComponents()
    {
        /* charger toutes les chanteurs */

        ArrayList <Chanteur> cha = daoCha.selectChanteurs();
        for (int i=0;i<cha.size();i++)
            jComboCha.addItem(cha.get(i));



    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonAnnul;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonOK;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboCha;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDateChooserDate;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextIdent;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextTitre;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private DAOAlbums daoAlb = Factory.getDAOAlbums();
    private DAOChanteurs daoCha = Factory.getDAOChanteurs();


}
```

Comment: can you please post the full stacktrace that occurs, not just the message?

Comment: @HamishD; I have edit my message

Comment: i have added an answer based on your image, let me know if it gives the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the image provided for clarification, i can see the comboBox is attempting to give you a string representation of your object `Chanteur`.

This is because you have

```
for (int i=0;i<cha.size();i++)
        jComboCha.addItem(cha.get(i));
```

`.get()` just returns the object, not a string value, if you want to return the `toString()` value of the object, modify the code to:

```
for (int i=0;i<cha.size();i++)
        jComboCha.addItem(cha.get(i).toString());
```

and it should work.

> Note: if iterating over an ArrayList like this, it may be preferable and perhaps simpler to use a for: each loop.

Comment: @julliiie what are you wanting to happen? i need clarification

Comment: @ HamishD ; I don't have error message however my dropdown list not charge as on the picture previously.

Comment: @julliiie so the image is what you want to happen, but currently you have nothing in combo box?

Comment: @ HamishD : the combo box shows only https://i.stack.imgur.com/49ilS.png

Comment: @julliiie and what do you want the combo box to show?

Comment: @ HamishD; the names of singers ; my erreurs messages are always as previously in fact https://zupimages.net/up/18/21/sy5z.png

Comment: Ah ok, so the nullpointer exception suggests your singers are not properly populated. can you edit your post and post the `daoCha` definition? specifically the method `selectChanteurs()`

Comment: @ HamishD : here is my class JIFChanteurs on the first message

Comment: @julliiie my guess would be something to do with `private DAOChanteurs daoCha = Factory.getDAOChanteurs();` not properly populating daoCha, which will in turn give you the `NullPointerException` when calling `.get` on it later in the program

Comment: @ HamishD ; hello my problem is resolve thank you a lot for your help. https://zupimages.net/up/18/21/0dld.png